# How can i solve this? (Integration)

Tags: integration

How I can solve this problem ?, I think using polar coordinates, but have the problem after using polar.

$$\int_0^\sqrt 2 \int_0^1 \dfrac{8x}{\left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^2}\,dy\,dx $$

Comment: already edited.

Comment: To start with try reversing the order of integration and then using a $u$ substitution $u=x^2+y^2+1$

Comment: If you reverse the order of integration, notice that $8x$ is four times the derivative of $x^2+y^2+1$ (with respect to $x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the substitution $u = x^2 + y^2 + 1\to du = 2x dx$ and perform the $x$-integral first

$$I = \int_{0}^1 \int_{1+y^2}^{3+y^2} \frac{4du}{u^2}dy= 4\int_{0}^1\left(\frac{1}{1+y^2} - \frac{1}{3+y^2}\right)dy$$

Now you can use $\int \frac{dz}{1+z^2} = \arctan(z) + C$ to finish it off.